# How to draw different images (generated from the same canvas) to another canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I want to add several different elements (image via `canvasAux`) to an array and draw them on `canvas`, but when adding the second item, the image of the first item is also changed (so on). How to solve this so that each element can have different images?

Example below:

Steps: Click "add", then click "change" and "add" again (or "add", "add", "change" and "add" again).
How to keep the first element with the Google logo and the others with the Yahoo logo (or any other)?

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var canvasAux = document.getElementById("canvasAux");

 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var contextAux = canvasAux.getContext("2d");

 var add = document.getElementById("add");
 var change = document.getElementById("change");

 var elements = [];

 function drawElements() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   context.drawImage(elements[i].image, elements[i].x, elements[i].y, elements[i].width, elements[i].height);
  }
 }

 var imageDefault = new Image();
 imageDefault.src = "https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

 imageDefault.onload = function() {
  contextAux.drawImage(imageDefault, 0, 0, canvasAux.width, canvasAux.height);
 }

 change.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var imageAux = new Image();
  imageAux.src = "https://s.yimg.com/zz/nn/lib/metro/g/my/yahoo_en-US_f_p_190x45_2x.png";

  imageAux.onload = function() {
   contextAux.clearRect(0, 0, canvasAux.width, canvasAux.height);
   contextAux.drawImage(imageAux, 0, 0, canvasAux.width, canvasAux.height);
  }
 });

 var x = 0;

 add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var element = {
   image: canvasAux,
   width: 163,
   height: 191,
   x: x,
   y: 0
  };

  elements.push(element);

  x += 170;

  drawElements();
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #333;">
 <button id="add">Add</button> <button id="change">Change</button>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>

 <canvas id="canvasAux" width="163" height="191" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you've got only one `canvasAux` element, so when you modify it, well... it's modified... And all `element`s do point to the same modified canvas. Why don't you simply store the `new Image` in your `element` objects instead?

Comment: @Kaiido but they are already stored on `var element = {image: canvasAux` object... I really need to do it this way, because in the `canvasAux` element I manipulate the chosen image (I just did not add it in the example to make it simple to understand the "problem"). I found this behavior strange, since each object has its own "image" value.

Comment: No, they don't, they all point to the **same** `<canvas>` element. If you do some modification from the canvas, then store a new canvas for each `element`. quick refactoring : https://jsfiddle.net/fvtk0eLn/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just creating a new canvas element in every `add` click:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var canvasAux = document.getElementById("canvasAux");

 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var contextAux = canvasAux.getContext("2d");

 var add = document.getElementById("add");
 var change = document.getElementById("change");

 var elements = [];

 function drawElements() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   context.drawImage(elements[i].image, elements[i].x, elements[i].y, elements[i].width, elements[i].height);
  }
 }

 var imageDefault = new Image();
 imageDefault.src = "https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

 imageDefault.onload = function() {
  contextAux.drawImage(imageDefault, 0, 0, canvasAux.width, canvasAux.height);
 }

 change.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var imageAux = new Image();
  imageAux.src = "https://s.yimg.com/zz/nn/lib/metro/g/my/yahoo_en-US_f_p_190x45_2x.png";

  imageAux.onload = function() {
   contextAux.clearRect(0, 0, canvasAux.width, canvasAux.height);
   contextAux.drawImage(imageAux, 0, 0, canvasAux.width, canvasAux.height);
  }
 });

 var x = 0;

 add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var imagesss = document.createElement("canvas");
  imagesss.width = canvasAux.width;
  imagesss.height = canvasAux.height;

  var contextsss = imagesss.getContext("2d");

  contextsss.drawImage(canvasAux, 0, 0, imagesss.width, imagesss.height);

  var element = {
   image: imagesss,
   width: 163,
   height: 191,
   x: x,
   y: 0
  };

  elements.push(element);

  x += 170;

  drawElements();
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #333;">
 <button id="add">Add</button> <button id="change">Change</button>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>

 <canvas id="canvasAux" width="163" height="191" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```